# Bash script for pull-mode backups via restic's rest-server

Tags: bash, security, encryption

I wrote the following Bash scripts to make pull-mode backups with [restic](https://restic.net/), a backup solution written in Golang, similar to Borg Backup. The main use case for this script is pulling backups into a central backup server that you trust, especially if you don't want to create a shell account or sftp user for every machine you backup, while still using a tool like restic on your own infrastructure.

This script is mostly just a wrapper for restic to talk to [rest-server](https://github.com/restic/rest-server) over SSH, using port forwarding. Rest-server allows for enforcing append-only mode, so clients shouldn't be able to delete their past backups.

The main developer of restic is interested in, or at least considering, making restic support pull-mode without rest-server. If that is released at some point, then it would probably make more sense to use restic directly, rather than this script.

A coworker with more BASH experience than me reviewed the codebase, and I merged in most of those patches, with some changes.

My main concern regarding this code is security, and was wondering if there are any ways I could improve it. One weakness is that restic's encryption password has to be stored somewhere, and so I store it in plain text on the backup server, with the expectation that the backups are encrypted by a LUKS partition and a password.

restic also uses its encryption password to verify backups, so I don't know if that complicates the security of this script. More details about my design choices are in the readme of the [source code repository](https://github.com/leaf-node/kaya).

I'm interested in hearing your thoughts. Thanks! : )

`kaya`:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

# This file is part of Kaya.
#
# Kaya is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# Kaya is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with Kaya.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
# Copyright 2021 Andrew Engelbrecht
#

if ! test "$BASH_VERSION"; then echo "error: shell is not bash" >&2; exit 1; fi
shopt -s inherit_errexit 2>/dev/null ||: # ignore fail in bash < 4.4
set -eE -o pipefail
trap 'echo "$0:$LINENO:error: \"$BASH_COMMAND\" exit status: $?, PIPESTATUS: ${PIPESTATUS[*]}" >&2' ERR


# first stable version of API between kaya and kaya-client
kaya_protocol_version=1

kaya-usage() {
    cat << EOF >&2

kaya usage:
kaya [-c CONFIG_PATH] [-u REMOTE_USER] HOST_TO_BACKUP backup -- RESTIC_ARGS

REMOTE_USER          Default is root
CONFIG_PATH          Default is /etc/kaya.conf
HOST_TO_BACKUP       For example www1.example.com
RESTIC_ARGS          See possible args by running "restic backup --help"
EOF
    exit "$1"
}

set-defaults() {
    global_conf="/etc/kaya.conf"
    remote_user="root"
}

get-params() {
    local -a positional
    local key
    while (( $# )); do
        key="$1"

        case $key in
            -c|--conf)
                global_conf="$2"
                shift 2
                ;;
            -u|--user)
                remote_user="$2"
                shift 2
                ;;
            --)
                shift
                backup_options=("$@")
                break
                ;;
            -*)
                echo "kaya: error: unrecognized argument: $key" >&2
                kaya-usage 1
                ;;
            *)
                positional+=("$key")
                shift
                ;;
        esac
    done

    set -- "${positional[@]}"

    hostname="$1"
    action="$2"

    if [[ -z $hostname ]]; then
        echo "kaya: error: missing hostname argument" >&2
        kaya-usage 1
    fi

    case $action in
        backup)
            # currently the only option is to backup
            ;;
        *)
            echo "kaya: error: invalid action argument: $action" >&2
            kaya-usage 1
            ;;
    esac
}

## create restic backup repo, store the new password in plaintext
create-backup-dir() {
    echo "kaya: Creating backup directory..."

    mkdir -p "${backup_dir}"; chmod 700 "${backup_dir}"
    touch "${password_file}"; chmod 600 "${password_file}"; pwgen 30 1 > "${password_file}"; chmod 400 "${password_file}"

    RESTIC_PASSWORD="$(cat "${password_file}")" restic -r "${backup_dir}" init > /dev/null
}

# check / create the hashed password in .htpasswd
update-htpasswd-file() {
    if [[ ! -e $htpasswd_file ]] ; then
        touch "${htpasswd_file}"
    fi
    chmod 600 "${htpasswd_file}"

    # check to see if the password is already there and correct
    # otherwise, update it
    if ! grep -q "^${hostname}" "${htpasswd_file}" || ! htpasswd -i -v "${htpasswd_file}" "${hostname}" < "${password_file}" &> /dev/null ; then

        flock -w 10 "${htpasswd_file}.flock" -c "htpasswd -i -B '${htpasswd_file}' '${hostname}'" < "${password_file}" \
            |& { grep -E -v "(Adding|Updating) password for user" >&2 ||:; }

        echo "kaya: Waiting for rest-server to reload .htpasswd... (mostly for new backups)"
        sleep 32
    fi
}

start-backup() {
    echo "kaya: Starting backup of ${hostname}"
    echo

    local password
    password="$(head -n1 "${password_file}")"

    # make the backup over a forwarded port
    cat << EOF | ssh -R "${remote_port}:localhost:${local_port}" "${remote_user}@${hostname}" kaya-client \
        "${remote_port@Q}" "${hostname@Q}" "${backup_options[@]@Q}"
${kaya_protocol_version}
${password}
EOF

}

main() {
    local program
    local missing_prog
    missing_prog=false
    for program in flock pwgen; do
        if ! type -p $program &>/dev/null; then
            echo "kaya: error: install $program (package $program on debian based systems)" >&2
        fi
    done
    if ! type -p htpasswd &>/dev/null; then
        echo "kaya: error: install htpasswd (package apache2-utils on debian based systems)" >&2
    fi
    if $missing_prog; then
        exit 1
    fi
    set-defaults
    get-params "$@"

    # shellcheck source=/etc/kaya.conf
    source "${global_conf}"
    if [[ -z $local_port ]]; then
        local_port=8000
    fi

    backup_dir="${backuproot}/${hostname}"
    password_file="${backup_dir}/repo-password-keep"
    htpasswd_file="${backuproot}/.htpasswd"

    if [[ ! -d $backup_dir ]]; then
        create-backup-dir
    fi

    if [[ ! -e $password_file ]]; then
        echo "kaya: error: the repo password file is missing:" >&2
        echo "${password_file}" >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    update-htpasswd-file

    if [[ $action == backup ]]; then
        start-backup
    fi
}

main "$@"
```

`kaya-client`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# This file is part of Kaya.
#
# Kaya is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# Kaya is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with Kaya.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
# Copyright 2021 Andrew Engelbrecht
#

if ! test "$BASH_VERSION"; then echo "error: shell is not bash" >&2; exit 1; fi
shopt -s inherit_errexit 2>/dev/null ||: # ignore fail in bash < 4.4
set -eE -o pipefail
trap 'echo "$0:$LINENO:error: \"$BASH_COMMAND\" exit status: $?, PIPESTATUS: ${PIPESTATUS[*]}" >&2' ERR

read -r kaya_protocol_version

if [[ $kaya_protocol_version != 1 ]] ; then
    echo "kaya-client: error: mismatched protocol version with kaya" >&2
    echo "kaya-client: error: kaya protocol version: ${kaya_protocol_version} kaya-client protocol version: 1" >&2
    exit 1
fi

read -r password

port="$1"
hostname="$2"
shift 2

username="${hostname}"
backupdir="${hostname}"

export RESTIC_REPOSITORY="rest:http://${username}:${password}@localhost:${port}/${backupdir}/"
export RESTIC_PASSWORD="${password}"

cmd=( restic backup "$@")
ret=0
"${cmd[@]}" || ret=$?

if (( ret )); then
    echo "kaya-client: command exit code $ret: ${cmd[*]}" >&2
    exit $ret
fi
```

`kaya.conf`:

````bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Config file for Kaya, a restic backup wrapper
#
# This will be sourced by bash

backuproot=/srv/backups/kaya

# set if using non-default port as in 'rest-server --listen :PORT'
# local_port=8000
remote_port=8777    # some aribtrary port
```
````